# SQLException Error Says Existing Column Doesn't Exist

Tags: java, derby, sqlexception

When running a searchQuery, I get a SQLException error saying that one of my columns cannot be found. This is very confusing, as I reference that column earlier in the code, and the program can find the column just fine at that point. do I have something wrong in the syntax? Thank you!

```
public void createDB(){    
    String createCharTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE CosplayCharacter (" +
                "CharacterID int NOT NULL primary key GENERATED ALWAYS " +
                "AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), " +
                "name varchar(60) not null," +
                "gender varchar(10)," +
                "genreID int, " +
                "universeID int, " +
                "mediaID int, " +
                "description varchar(60))";

      statement.executeUpdate(createCharTableSQL);
}

public void insertCharacter(){    
  String fetchAllDataSQL = "SELECT * from CosplayCharacter";


    //Code can find the universeID column here
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(fetchAllDataSQL);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String name = resultSet.getString("name");
            int universeCharID = resultSet.getInt("universeID");

            System.out.println("Character Name : " + name +
                    " UniverseID : " + universeCharID);
        }
}

//But returns error here
public void searchCharacter(String characterName){
    String fetchAllDataSQL = "SELECT * from CosplayCharacter where name = '" + characterName +"'";

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(fetchAllDataSQL);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String gender = resultSet.getString("gender");
            int genreID = resultSet.getInt("genreID");
//Method to search a column in a joined table; no error
            String genreName = getGenreName(genreID);
            int universeID = resultSet.getInt("universeID");
   }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Column 'universeID' not found.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown  
Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example? I don't think the code you've shared compiles because e.g. `String fetchAllDataSQL` is declared twice. Perhaps you've left out something relevant while copy-pasting?

Comment: Sorry those two are in two separate methods, and the methods themselves are really long so I sliced them up. I'll edit the question so that's clearer.

Comment: Thanks. What happens in `getGenreName`? Does that method by chance move the cursor in the result set? One problem in this code is that `resultSet` is a global variable (a field in your class), so it's hard to see what parts of the code can change its state.

Comment: This code still doesn't compile, as `resultSet` isn't declared anywhere. Observing this, is it possible that `getGenreName` is using the same `resultSet` and thus is overwriting the result set with data from another table, making it so that no `universeID` column exists when you call `resultSet.getInt("universeID")` afterwards?

Comment: I don't see why you've declared `resultSet` outside each individual method, as the values from one method's use of `resultSet` don't appear applicable to other methods. Your code will likely be more clear, and your issue potentially fixed, if you change `resultSet` from a class variable to a local variable within each method used.

Comment: That fixed it. Looks like the resultSet that I was using in getGenreName overrode the resultSet in my main searchCharacter method. The getGenreName doesn't have a universeID in it, so thus the error. Thank you.

Comment: A lesson to learn here: minimize the scope of your variables and avoid globals. Also, you should remember to close your `Statement`s e.g. using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Finally, whenever your query is using input variables (as is the case in `searchCharacter`), you should use [`PreparedStatements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), instead of concatenating the input string into the query.

Answer (score 0):

ResultSet was used globally. ResultSet used in getGenreName method override the resultSet in the main searchCharacter method. Solution: set ResultSet variable individually in each method.